# SHS module in drupal 7 views

Tags: theming, views

I am using [Simple hierarchical select](https://www.drupal.org/project/shs) module and I am having terms lists like below;

1. India

   a) Karnataka

   - Bangalore

So, I want this filed as exposed filter in my views. Let me give example, assume if 3 nodes are selected "Bangalore".

So, whenever I select the "India" or "Karnataka" means it should shows the content which is selected as "Bangalore" in views.

How should I achieve this process?

Any configuration has to be done?

Can anyone please help me out in this case?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Add filter  "Content: Has taxonomy terms (with depth; Simple hierarchical select)"

2) choose your vocabulary

3) in the selection type choose  "Simple hierarchical select"

4) select Depth 2 and click on save.

5) Tick in the "Expose this filter to visitors,"

Here the trick is in the Depth selection

Comment: Awesome man its cool tricky thing :) Then one more request, have you used https://www.drupal.org/project/cshs ever?
Because I need the same set up for this module also in views. can you please help me out, since I cant see the depth field in views when am using this module.

Comment: Yes i used cshs module, cshs module do not allow you to search in the depth. using cshs you must select the terms to the deepest level otherwise cshs will give you no results.

Comment: Thanks for response. Yeah CSHS wont allow to search through parent term. I hope you have used both of that SHS and CSHS.
CSHS is more speed compare to SHS, is there any chance to increare the speed of SHS module UI? can you please help me out in this case?

Comment: This problem is discussed on the module page, you can use  High-performance JavaScript callback handler

Comment: Thanks, hey as well as I want to take the super parent in drupal 7 views. for example I need to display India as a parent term for Bangalore not karnataka.

Comment: Sorry i didn't get your point, can you explane a little bit?

Comment: Hey thanks for your request, I will explain now what I am exactly looking for. Am using taxonomy with Super parent, parent, child, i.e (2 depth). So, I gave term reference on one content type, while adding content I will select the child (Bangalore). So, in views I want to display the super parent of child term, i.e I dont want to display karnataka, I want to display India as a parent. So, how should I make view to bring this? any idea? please share here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Edit your view and then click on the shs field from the fields list, then in the Formatter drop down list select "simple hierarchy" and save. in the front end you can hide the child's using css if you do not want the child's to display.

Answer (score 0):

I presume you already set your Taxonomy and your node has add field (example: you name this field as "Place")for select either Bangalorem, India or Karnataka.

In the views, add FILTER CRITERIA. Select Content: Place. Selection type: You can choose dropbox. Save the view. Last, click on the same CRITERIA again (example: Content: Place (= )) and choose  Bangalorem